# Reverse words without changing capitals or punctuation

Tags: java, string

Create a program with the lowest amount of characters to reverse each word in a string while keeping the order of the words, as well as punctuation and capital letters, in their initial place.

By "Order of the words", I mean that each word is split by an empty space (" "), so contractions and such will be treated as one word. The apostrophe in contractions should stay in the same place. ("Don't" => "Tno'd").

(Punctuation means any characters that are not a-z, A-Z or whitespace*).

```
Numbers were removed from this list due to the fact that you cannot have capital numbers. Numbers are now treated as punctuation.
```

For example, for the input:

> Hello, I am a fish.

it should output:

> Olleh, I ma a hsif.

Notice that O, which is the first letter in the first word, is now capital, since H was capital before in the same location.

The comma and the period are also in the same place.

More examples:

> This; Is Some Text!

would output

> Siht; Si Emos Txet!

I've tried this:

```
 public static String reverseWord(String input)
    {
         
        String words[]=input.split(" ");
         StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
       
          for (String string : words) {
              String revStr = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
              result.append(revStr).append(" ");
          }
        return result.toString().trim();
        
    }
```

Comment: Show some code that you tried.

Comment: *Hint:* The solution, in addition to all the normal "reverse word" logic, is to call [`Character.isUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-) on the letter in the input string, and then call either [`Character.toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-) or [`Character.toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-) on the character at the same index in the result string.

Comment: What's the output of the above program you tried?

Comment: output is just reversed the string but we have to change the index of the capital letter

Comment: Hi, if any answer suits your need, do you mind "accepting" it? This will help the community and reward those who help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem. It's working fine for the examples I have checked :) Please look and let me know :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(reverseWord("This; Is Some Text!"));
}

public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s) {
    return s != null && s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
}

public static String reverseWord(String input)
{

    String words[]=input.split(" ");
    StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (isAlphaNumeric(Character.toString(input.charAt(i)))) {
            endIndex++;
        } else {
            String string = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            startIndex = ++endIndex;

            StringBuilder revStr = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int j = 0; j < string.length(); j++) {
                char charToAdd = string.charAt(string.length() - j - 1);
                if (Character.isUpperCase(string.charAt(j))) {
                    revStr.append(Character.toUpperCase(charToAdd));
                } else {
                    revStr.append(Character.toLowerCase(charToAdd));
                }
            }
            result.append(revStr);
            result.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
      if(endIndex>startIndex) // endIndex != startIndex
        {
            String string = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            result.append(string);
        }
    return result.toString().trim();

}
```

Call the reverseWord with your test string.
Hope it helps. Don't forget to mark it as right answer, if it is :)

Comment: Hi, I think you don't manage when the input ends by a single letter, for example if input string is `Hello, I am a fIsh. X`

Comment: @bsaverino I have edited the answer. See if it is fine now.

Comment: Yeah it works, but very like me (initially) you forgot the 'contractions' requirement whereas f.i. `"Don't"` should translate to `"Tno'd"` as @suhail asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal that follows your requirements. It may seem very long but its just comments and aerated code; and everybody loves comments.

```
public static String smartReverseWords(String input) {
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    // Word accumulator, resetted after each "punctuation" (or anything different than a letter)
    StringBuilder wordAcc = new StringBuilder(); 
    int processedChars = 0;
    
    for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        // If not a whitespace nor the last character
        if(!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {  
            // Accumulate letters 
            wordAcc.append(c);   
            
            // Have I reached the last character? Then finalize now:
            if(processedChars == input.length()-1) {
                reverseWordAndAppend(wordAcc, finalString);
            }
        }        
        else {
            // Was a word accumulated?
            if(wordAcc.length() > 0) {
                reverseWordAndAppend(wordAcc, finalString);
            }
            // Append non-letter char to final string:
            finalString.append(c);
        }
        processedChars++;
    }
    return finalString.toString();
}

private static void reverseWordAndAppend(StringBuilder wordAcc, StringBuilder finalString) {
    // Then reverse it:
    smartReverse(wordAcc);  // a simple wordAcc.reverse() is not possible

    // Append word to final string:
    finalString.append(wordAcc.toString());
    
    // Reset accumulator 
    wordAcc.setLength(0);        
}

private static class Marker {
    Integer position;
    String character;
}

private static void smartReverse(StringBuilder wordAcc) {
    char[] arr = wordAcc.toString().toCharArray();
    wordAcc.setLength(0);  // clean it for now
    
    // Memorize positions of 'punctuation' + build array free of 'punctuation' in the same time:
    List<Marker> mappedPosOfNonLetters = new ArrayList<>();     // order matters
    List<Integer> mappedPosOfCapitals = new ArrayList<>();      // order matters
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char c = arr[i];
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            Marker mark = new Marker();
            mark.position = i;
            mark.character = c+"";
            mappedPosOfNonLetters.add(mark);
        }
        else {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                mappedPosOfCapitals.add(i);
            }
            wordAcc.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }
    
    // Reverse cleansed word:
    wordAcc.reverse();

    // Reintroduce 'punctuation' at right place(s)
    for (Marker mark : mappedPosOfNonLetters) {
        wordAcc.insert(mark.position, mark.character);
    }
    // Restore capitals at right place(s)
    for (Integer idx : mappedPosOfCapitals) {
        wordAcc.setCharAt(idx,Character.toUpperCase(wordAcc.charAt(idx)));
    }    
}
```

**EDIT**

I've updated the code to take all your requirements into account. Indeed we have to make sure that "punctuation' stay in place (and capitals also) but also within a word, like a contraction.

Therefore given the following input string:

```
"Hello, I am on StackOverflow. Don't tell anyone."
```

The code produces this output:

```
"Olleh, I ma no WolfrEvokcats. Tno'd llet enoyna."
```